# How to filter response in http request. Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How can I filter the response? I want to show only the name and the phone number. Not email or password. I have also attached a screenshot of the database and the response.

**Request Function**

```
router.get('/name/:id', async(req, res) => {
    const user = await Model.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
    if (user)
        res.status(200).json(user);
    else
        res.status(500).json({ message: "User doesn't exist" });
})
```

**Here's the DB**

[image]

**Here's the response I am currently getting**

[image]

Comment: see [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection) part, you can project required fields in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways to do it:

First way (filter them manually)

```
router.get('/name/:id', async(req, res) => {
    const user = await Model.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
    if (user)
        res.status(200).json({fName:user.fName,sName:user.lName});
    else
        res.status(500).json({ message: "User doesn't exist" });
})
```

Second way (use projection from Mongo) Here's an example of me passing the projection object as a second argument to findOne:

```
router.get('/name/:id', async(req, res) => {
    const user = await Model.findOne({ _id: req.params.id },{fName:1,sName:1});
    if (user)
        res.status(200).json(user); //will give you what you selected in the projection
    else
        res.status(500).json({ message: "User doesn't exist" });
})
```

Comment: what if i had to exclude one item out of a big response. i can;t manually type everything. you know what i am saying

Comment: You can do the opposite for the projection object. It will look like: ```{fName:0}``` this will exclude fName field

Answer (score 1):

In mongoose you can specify fields to show like below:
// after findOne query and assigning it to user
user.select('name phoneNumber')

Between field names add one space, for more information checkout docs

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html